# Canvas placement with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onresize

I am trying to draw 2 arrows on canvas elements and place them on the left and right of the screen, in the middle of its height. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wzt5j/9/

In the site i am trying this ( http://bit.ly/JV5I0Z ), the images are drawn but the "placeArrows" function does not get called when i resize the window. In the fiddle window they aren't even drawn and i'm not sure what is the problem.

Comment: I updated it in JSFiddle, see if resolves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have JS errors during resize.
thumdList (line 150) and marginDiv (line 156) are null.

This stops your script.

Comment: apparently, i was trying to use elements that weren't there yet in my 2nd called function (redrawThumbs) in "onresize". i fixed it with a check to see if the elements existed first

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the fiddle not working is because JSFiddle is stupid. The functions you define are only defined inside its wrapper function, and so can't be accessed by anything else. Solve this pain in the arse by declaring your functions as `myfunction = function() {...}`.

As for the failing to resize, I don't see any code that listens for `onresize`. Add this: `window.onresize = placeArrows;`.

Comment: i have it on the body: <body id="body" onResize="placeArrows();">

edit: i have fixed the fiddle. now the arrows appear but again they won't reposition. also i noticed that i had not put onresize on the body, even though i did have it in my code. i removed it while trying to figure out why the arrows are not drawn and forgot to write it back

Comment: now they appear and reposition in the fiddle window lol. but in my site they don't :( what could be wrong

Comment: The body does not resize. The window does. You must put `window.onresize = placeArrows;` in your JS.

Comment: What was causing this not to work was that in another function was trying to reference these items before they were created, so the code stopped there. I put that inside an if to check if they existed before they were referenced and the code proceeded to work.